# mysqli prepared statement bind result and loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code in purpose to search in the database :

```
$key = '%'.$_GET['key'].'%';
$result= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM information WHERE stuId LIKE ? 
                                            OR stuName LIKE ? LIMIT ?,10");
$result->bind_param('ssi',$key,$key,$startpage);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($stuId,$stuName,$date,$stuSex,$stuAdd);
while($result->fetch()) {
    $stuDoB= $date->format('d/m/Y');
    echo "<tr>
              <td class='col1'>
                  <div>$stuId</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <div><a href='editStudent.php?stuId=$stuId'>" . htmlspecialchars($stuName) . "</a></div>
              </td>
              <td class='col3'>
                 <div>$stuDoB</div>
              </td>
              <td class='col4'>
                 <div>$stuSex</div>
              </td>
              <td class='col5'>
                 <div>" . htmlspecialchars($stuAdd) . "</div>
              </td>
            </tr>";
}
```

Im trying to learn prepared statement, so I change from normal way to above code 
Could you tell me :

- Do I have to bind_result inside the `$result->fetch()` or just 1 time `bind_result()` outside the loop?
- Is there any problem with my code ? It's always give an empty row result with any $key and a fatal error :
  `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\baiTapLon\showPage.php on line 30`

Line 30 is `$stuDoB= $date->format('d/m/Y');`

Please help me out.

Comment: there's only 3 ? in your prepare but you're passing 4 vars in in your bind.  also $key is a string so should be wrapped in ' inside the sql statement even in prepared statements I think (though not 100% on that one)

Answer (score 0):

- Do I have to bind_result inside the $result->fetch() or just 1 time bind_result() outside the loop?

**You have to use `bind_result` once means outside the loop**

- Is there any problem with my code ? It's alway give an empty row result with any $key and a fatal error :
  "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\baiTapLon\showPage.php on line 30"

**You can't use format for any variable** use it like this

```
$date1 = new DateTime($date);
$stuDoB= $date1->format('d/m/Y');
```